# Prohibit breaking the sequence for rows field (no gaps)

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

Is there a way to creacte check or index or anything else to prohibit breaking the sequence for rows field?

Let assume I have chapters table with order column.

Chapter table:

```
uuid | order
dad  | 1
1dd  | 2
xxss | 3
sdsd | 4
5aa  | 5
```

Chapters order start from 1 and should not contain sequence gaps like 1,2,4,5 (3 is missing). Any chapter can be deleted, or inserted in any order (with reordering).

If there is no way to forbid skips, then how can i reoder chapters after insert or delete to erase skips (reoder from 1 to max)?

Comment: You cannot do that with a sequence.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe oh, it's just int column, not a sequence

Answer (score 2):

I am unsure that there is an easy way to prevent gaps. I would start with a unique constraint, that avoids duplicates.

Then, you can use a view that assigns an autoincrementing id based on the existing column:

```
create view myview as
select uuid, row_number() over(order by ord) as new_ord
from mytable
```

Whenever you want to display the sequential chapter numbers, you can query the view instead of the table.

Note: `order` is a language keyword; I used `ord` instead in the query.

Comment: thanks, if there is no easy way to forbid gaps, them i think it's more convenient to just update order values in one transaction after insert, delete or order change.